# How can I set a flatpak application to run on startup?

Tags: linux, startup, flatpak

I wanted to post this because I didn't find the answer elsewhere and this might just help someone else.

I have Slack installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver via FlatPak and would like to have it launch as soon as I login.
Because it is installed via FlatPak, I cannot find it in /usr/share/applications in order to add it to startup applications

Answer (score 14):

You need to install FlatPak applications via Gnome Tweaks.  If you haven't already installed Gnome tweaks then run

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Launch Gnome Tweaks and navigate to "Startup Applications".

[image]

The flatPak applications are easily found from here.

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically correct to say "run on startup", it is better to say "**run on login**" in this case.

An `flatpak` application like [**Slack**](https://flathub.org/apps/com.slack.Slack) should be launched after the user logged in, and not before that.
But a `flatpak` application like [**Jellyfin Server**](https://flathub.org/apps/org.jellyfin.JellyfinServer) could also start regardless if the user logged in, so this is more akin to "run on startup".

I point this out because there are many scenarios and different ways to achieve them.
The Arch-Linux wiki covers many of them, based on Desktop-Environment, Window-Manager, etc.:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Autostarting

Now to return to Ubuntu and **Gnome**:

When adding a startup application via **Gnome Tweaks**, a `.desktop` file is created under `~/.config/autostart`.

With that in mind one can create custom `.desktop` files in that directory.
For example here is a custom file to launch flatpak's [**PCSX2**](https://flathub.org/apps/net.pcsx2.PCSX2) after the user logged in:

`cat ~/.config/autostart/test-PCSX2.desktop`

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=test-PCSX2
Exec=flatpak run net.pcsx2.PCSX2
```

These files can be tested by logging-out and logging-in again, no full restart needed :)

Answer (score -3):

You could add an entry to your .gnomerc, .Xinitrc etc such as

snap run (program)

Comment: flatpak is discussed here, nothing about snap